# Right turn only puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, letters

Here is a grid with 24 spaces filled with letters.

Pick any place to start your travel in the grid taking right turns only. You must get to all remaining 23 spaces but only once. By doing so create a 24 letter phrase that ends in the E at the corner. From your space number 1, you can go in any direction except diagonally.After taking the right turn you can go as many spaces as you want. Again, you cannot repeat the same space.

What is the phrase?

[image: 4×6-grid-of-letters]

Comment: Are diagonal moves allowed at *any* point? Or are those right turns always 90 degree turns?

Comment: No diagonals. Only 90 degrees  Thanks

Comment: I completely didn't understand that the letters passed while going straight don't count (not part of the phrase, can be passed multiple times). This leaves only one way to pass all letters, which doesn't form a phrase. Instead, I started thinking that “right turns” might mean “90 degrees turns” instead of “not left turns”.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The phrase is

> "kill two birds with one stone"

The order of "right turns" is as follows:

> [image]

Comment: That was fast. Very Nice.

Comment: Took a little bit to realize I could "jump".  Then I just chose the most uncommon letter and thought I would work backward from there, but turned out it was moving forward.  Nice puzzle!